# Alignment Tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, sidewaystable

I have difficulties aligning my tables.

First thing is that Latex puts a distance between 2 tables alone on a page. I want the normal distance between them and the rest of the page just empty. Not both equally distributed on a page.

Second I have a lonely sidewaystable and it is centered. I want it to start at the top of the page and as before the rest of the page empty. So a vertical alignment for a landscape page. I managed that for normal tables with that \makeatletter...

```
\RequirePackage{rotating}
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, listof=totoc, footlines=2, ngerman,english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float
\setlength\@fptop{0\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Something}
    \label{tab:14}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{No.} &\textbf{AAAAAA} & \textbf{BBBBBB}& \textbf{CCCCCC}& \textbf{DDDDDD}& \textbf{EEEEEE}& \textbf{F} \\
        \midrule
        600 & 600 & 100 & 200 & 100 & -   & -  \\
        600 & 600 & 100 & 200 & -   & 100 & -  \\
        600 & 600 & 100 & 200 & -   & -   & 100\\
        600 & 600 & 100 & 250 & 50  & -   & -  \\
        600 & 600 & 100 & 250 & -   & 50  & -  \\
        600 & 600 & 100 & 250 & -   & -   & 50 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Something1}
    \label{tab:15}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{AAAA} &\textbf{BBBB}/nm & \textbf{CCCCC}/\% & \textbf{DDDDD}/s& \textbf{EEEEE}/J& \textbf{FFFFFF}/N\\
        \midrule
        600 & - & 123 & 123 & -  & 12345 \\
        600 & - & 123 & 123 & -  & - \\
        600 & - & 123 & 123 & -  & - \\
        600 & 600.7 & 600.5 & 4.01 & -  & - \\
        600 & 600.0 & 600.9 & 2.73 & -  & - \\
        600 & 600.3 & 600.7 & 1.75 & -  & - \\ 
        600 & 600.7 & 600.9 & 2.40 & -  & - \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{LALALALALALALALALALAL}
    \label{tab:16}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{No.} &\textbf{AAAAAAAAA} &\textbf{AAAAAAAAAA} & \textbf{VVVVVVV} &\textbf{XXX} &\textbf{AAAA} & \textbf{CCCCT}& \textbf{XXNT}& \textbf{BIBIBI} \\
        \midrule
        600 & 614 & 650 & 100 & 200 & 50  & -   & -   & 50\\
        600 & 614 & 650 & 100 & 200 & 50  & -   & -   & 80\\
        600 & 615 & 650 & 100 & 200 & -   & 50  & -   & 50\\
        600 & 615 & 650 & 100 & 200 & -   & 50  & -   & 80\\
        600 & 616 & 650 & 100 & 200 & -   & -   & 50  & 50\\
        600 & 616 & 650 & 100 & 200 & -   & -   & 50  & 80\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Maybe i should use more minipages, cause that floating sucks sometimes.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the optional argument `[!htb]` for the first two tables. For the sideways table,add `\hfill` just before `\begin{tabular}`.

Unrelated,  I replaced the hyphens in the tables with  more correct endashes.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, listof=totoc, footlines=2, ngerman,english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float
\setlength\@fptop{0\p@}
\makeatother
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{1ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Something}
    \label{tab:14}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{No.} &\textbf{AAAAAA} & \textbf{BBBBBB}& \textbf{CCCCCC}& \textbf{DDDDDD}& \textbf{EEEEEE}& \textbf{F} \\
        \midrule
        600 & 600 & 100 & 200 & 100 & – & – \\
        600 & 600 & 100 & 200 & – & 100 & – \\
        600 & 600 & 100 & 200 & – & – & 100\\
        600 & 600 & 100 & 250 & 50 & – & – \\
        600 & 600 & 100 & 250 & – & 50 & – \\
        600 & 600 & 100 & 250 & – & – & 50 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Something1}
    \label{tab:15}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{AAAA} &\textbf{BBBB}/nm & \textbf{CCCCC}/\% & \textbf{DDDDD}/s& \textbf{EEEEE}/J& \textbf{FFFFFF}/N\\
        \midrule
        600 & – & 123 & 123 & – & 12345 \\
        600 & – & 123 & 123 & – & – \\
        600 & – & 123 & 123 & – & – \\
        600 & 600.7 & 600.5 & 4.01 & – & – \\
        600 & 600.0 & 600.9 & 2.73 & – & – \\
        600 & 600.3 & 600.7 & 1.75 & – & – \\
        600 & 600.7 & 600.9 & 2.40 & – & – \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\clearpage
{\rotFPtop = 0pt plus 0.18 fil
\begin{sidewaystable}[
\centering
\caption{LALALALALALALALALALAL}
\label{tab:16}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{No.} &\textbf{AAAAAAAAA} &\textbf{AAAAAAAAAA} & \textbf{VVVVVVV} &\textbf{XXX} &\textbf{AAAA} & \textbf{CCCCT}& \textbf{XXNT}& \textbf{BIBIBI} \\
        \midrule
        600 & 614 & 650 & 100 & 200 & 50 & – & – & 50\\
        600 & 614 & 650 & 100 & 200 & 50 & – & – & 80\\
        600 & 615 & 650 & 100 & 200 & – & 50 & – & 50\\
        600 & 615 & 650 & 100 & 200 & – & 50 & – & 80\\
        600 & 616 & 650 & 100 & 200 & – & – & 50 & 50\\
        600 & 616 & 650 & 100 & 200 & – & – & 50 & 80\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}}
```

[image] 
[image]

Comment: I tried the [!htb] already in my original file, it doesn't work. I don't know why it works here and not in my other document. U took me wrong with the second one. I mean not to the top of a portrait page, i mean to the top of the landscape page. So if u want to the left margin of a portrait page. But thanks for the endashes :)!

Comment: @sandor_123: I've updated my answer. For the sideways table, I have a solution by trial and error, modifying   the value of `\rotFPtop`. For the horizontal tables, could you post a small example reproducing the problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks! So the sidewaystable works fine, also with the \vspace command u posted before. I took that one before u posted the second one. Hope its fine, or why did u change it? I managed to align also the 2 other tables. it worked with a \clearpage before :D. Thanks a lot

Comment: I change it to when I saw these two glue lengths – \rotFPtop and \rotFPbot – in the documentation of rotating, just to use the ‘legal’  tools, also because one is never too sure there  isn't a side effect.